# soundTransform is muting the sound but sound still plays

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using the following code, in the last line when I play the sound I can still hear it even when I have transformed it to 0.

```
var tempTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0,0.5);
clickSoundChannel = clickSound.play();
clickSoundChannel.soundTransform = tempTransform;
clickSound.play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `clickSound.play()` twice, and you're only muting the first one.